# Сгруппировать pandas DataFrame по author_name и отобразить топ-10 авторов по количеству коммитов

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame (https://drive.google.com/file/d/10plr5SRXT4iqMDoE1Lfev1R2bs-h_DIp/view?usp=sharing) и надо сгрупировать его по полю author_name и вывести топ 10 записей по коллчеству коммитов (коммит это одна запись в файле).
Пробовал такой вариант, но неправильно работает

```
df.groupby('author_name').mean()
```

Comment: Попробуйте `.size()`, а потом ещё получившийся датафрейм нужно будет отсортировать через `.sort_values` по этому новому полю, я так сходу не помню как оно будет называться.

Comment: @CrazyElf попробовал вот так, но как-то оно странно сортирует, но считает уже нормально ```df.groupby('author_name').size().sort_values().tail(10)```

Comment: df.groupby("author_name", as_index=False).size().sort_values("size", ascending=False).iloc[:10,0]

Comment: @strawdog вот так работает как надо ```df.groupby("author_name", as_index=False).size().sort_values("size", ascending=False).head(10)```